# Binding to datacontext from Resources

Tags: c#, wpf

I've defined a contextmenu in a usercontrols resources, the user controls datacontext is set to a separate viewmodel, which holds a property that I want to bind to.

```
<UserControl>
 <UserControl.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
     <ContextMenu>
       <MenuItem Visiblity="{Binding IsVisible}"/>
     </ContextMenu>
   <ResourceDictionary>

 <Grid x:Name="MyGrid">

 </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here the Visiblity Property is defined the DataContext of the UserControl. Since the DataContext is set like this:

```
(Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = myViewModel;
```

I suspect that "Content" is not including the `UserControl.Resources`. I think I would need some RelativSource stuff in my binding, but how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `RelativeSource`,  if `IsVisible` property is located in viewmodel.

For example:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
              <StackPanel>
                  <TextBlock Text="Hello, World!" />
                  <CheckBox x:Name="MainContentArea" IsChecked="{Binding IsVisible}" />
              </StackPanel>
          </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```